# Incomplete ControlTemplate for ComboBox in Visual studio 2015 & .NET 4.0

Tags: wpf, xaml

**Problem #1**. When I execute **Edit template** > **Edit a copy** on ComboBox control in “Microsoft blend” or “Visual studio 2015” in a project for .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.0 client profile I am getting partial, incomplete template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0L3.5,4 7,0z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition>
                        <Condition.Value>
                            <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
                        </Condition.Value>
                    </Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

and an error message **InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Property'**. which is very annoying & strange.

**Problem #2**. When I finally managed to retrive full template ([WPF: The Simplest Way to Get the Default Template of a Control as XAML](https://www.manuelmeyer.net/2014/08/wpf-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-default-template-of-a-control-as-xaml/)) & tried to use it in the program I find out that I am unable to do this because of new errors related to the template:

```
Cannot find the Template Property 'IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel'.
```

and

```
The member "IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

I added full template into window`s resource & for some unknown reasons template is defined as a Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="ComboBox" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
…
<Setter Property="Control.Template">
…
</Setter>
…
</Style>
```

What I need to do is to remove arrow from ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all template for the same control differs depending on .NET framework version & current OS theme (Aero, Classic etc). Second, method described in [WPF: The Simplest Way to Get the Default Template of a Control as XAML](https://www.manuelmeyer.net/2014/08/wpf-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-default-template-of-a-control-as-xaml/) is not very useful because template received in such a way does not have necessary functionality achieved via bindings (in other words template does not have necessary bindings to work as it should). As example **IsOpen** property. ComboBox with template received in a way described in [WPF: The Simplest Way to Get the Default Template of a Control as XAML](https://www.manuelmeyer.net/2014/08/wpf-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-default-template-of-a-control-as-xaml/) could not be opened because it`s **IsOpen** property does not have necessary binding. It's IsOpen property value is simply **False** but it should be **{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}**. Comparison:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
```

VS

```
<Popup IsOpen="False" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" AllowsTransparency="True" Name="PART_Popup" Margin="1,1,1,1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
```

And finally, template generated by Microsoft expression blend for Visual studio 2015 for ComboBox control for project targeting .NET framework 4 contains invalid code in Triggers section of template! Here it is:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
        <Condition>
            <Condition.Value>
                <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
            </Condition.Value>
        </Condition>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Full working template of ComboBox with replaced invalid code for .NET framework 4 & Aero theme:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0L3.5,4 7,0z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--<MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                <Condition>
                    <Condition.Value>
                        <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
                    </Condition.Value>
                </Condition>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
        </MultiTrigger>-->
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <System:Boolean>False</System:Boolean>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Trigger.Value>
                <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```